# failed parsing overlays - Aapt2 - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, parsing, overlays, aapt2

I'm trying to use dlib in Android Studio for my university's project.
I did import all the .so files that I needed, but I can't import the `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat`... (I want to import it as a raw file)

I get `AAPT2 error: check logs for details` and the Java compiler says `failed parsing overlays`. Do you know what can I do to fix this ? I've never seen a topic about `failed parsing overlays`.

I already tried to put `android.enableAapt2=false` in the `gradle.properties` and the `testOptions` in the `gradle.build` without success...

You can find the build log here : [Build log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G93lb.png)

And the project here : https://github.com/ghysc/Stage

If you need any more information, please let me know.

Thanks for reading.

Cyril G

Comment: It means there's something wrong with your resources (or resources coming from your dependencies). Either post a link to your project on github/bitbucket or post the whole build log here.

Comment: Hello Izabela, thanks for taking time to help me !
I just updated my post so you can see the build log and my project on GitHub.
I tried to import dlib from another project on GitHub ( : https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android-app) so what you said is possible ! I don't really know how dependencies work...

Answer (score 7):

Using your GitHub project I found out it was a problem with one of the resource files you had - it was too big for AAPT2 to process:

> ./app/src/main/res/raw/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat

This was a bug in AAPT2 but it has been fixed recently.
So if you update your android gradle plugin version in your build.gradle file to 3.2.0-alpha11 or newer it all compiles fine:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha11'
```

Comment: I deleted the raw mp4 file that was causing me a problem, as this file was not necessary for the app.

Comment: @SoonSantos you can still keep the file if you update to gradle plugin 3.2.0-alpha11 or newer (there's a beta out right now, it's pretty stable and has some very nice fixes in it).

Comment: Updating gradle plugin or gradle version does not give me any problem? Actually, when clonning android opensource apps from github I am getting this error "cannot locate JAR for module 'grade-dependency-management'", I think it is because these apps have very old plugin versions as 2.2.2. I think upgrading the version will fix this issue, but I am not sure to which version I can update. Maybe upgrading to a newer version will cause me more problems with these apps.

Answer (score 1):

Huh, actually I just solved this problem in another way.
When I imported the project of tzutalin ( : github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android-app), I changed the name of the package, which is why my program couldn't find where the library where stored !

I re-named the package `package com.tzutalin.dlib;` for the dlib library and everything is fine now.